# How to set a density in emulator android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I would like to create an emulator of Samsung Galaxy XCover4S (720 x 1280 px (5.00") 294ppi 64.6% screen-to-body ratio). However I found only how to set a predefined densities (like 120,240,320) and many more densities (ppi) in .android\avd\~~\config. Is there a posibility to set it as 294?

Greetings

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. It is not possible to set the density to 294.

You can only choose between the following DPIs:
`120, 160, 213, 240, 280, 320, 360, 400, 420, 480, 560, 640`

---

To set the density, do the following:
After creating the emulator, open `~/.android/avd/my_avd/config.ini` and append:
`hw.lcd.density=560`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a custom emulator skin, check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds).

Comment: This post looks very old. Have you tested it? I just want to change a density not to create the whole emulator (which I already created via android studio)

Comment: I haven't, but it seems it's doable anyways. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

Comment: "Specify additional hardware-specific device configurations in a hardware.ini file for the device settings, such as hw.keyboard and hw.lcd.density." When I do this the emulator doesn't works. I can only specify density of:320 and 280

Comment: Does the custom emulator start at all?

Comment: Of course, just somehow I need to change a density. But I don't think this is possible as npkllr said in answers