# Cannot edit AVD hardware profile screen density

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I cannot find, how to change the screen density in a new AVD hardware profile:

[image]

I'm trying to emulate the Samsung A10 for development purposes but cannot end up with the right output... Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: You can find an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58397033/11793333